# Is it possible to use Pydantic BaseModel orm_mode to get data from gui class

Tags: python, pydantic

Is it possible to use model class which inherit from Pydantic.BaseModel to get data from a GUI class by setting orm_mode= true, like it used with databases

```
from typing import List
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from pydantic import BaseModel, constr

Base = declarative_base()


class CompanyOrm(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'companies'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    public_key = Column(String(20), index=True, nullable=False, unique=True)
    name = Column(String(63), unique=True)
    domains = Column(ARRAY(String(255)))


class CompanyModel(BaseModel):
    id: int
    public_key: constr(max_length=20)
    name: constr(max_length=63)
    domains: List[constr(max_length=255)]

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

''''
If it is possible how may i do it ?

Comment: What problem are you facing ? That this is possible, I showed on the example of an ordinary class below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is assumed that `ORM mode` supports arbitrary classes, not just databases ORM (it is named so because it is usually used in conjunction with it). More detailed [here](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#orm-mode-aka-arbitrary-class-instances).

Example with regular class:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = 100
        self.name = "some_name"


class SomeModel(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


print(SomeModel.from_orm(SomeClass()))  # id=100 name='some_name'
```